# Phantom Parameter in Python

Tags: python, methods, pyqt5, arguments, parameter-passing

I have this line of python code that connects a function when a text inside a line edit is changed:

```
self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText("Search...")    
self.lineEdit_3.textChanged.connect(self.search)
```

This is the search function inside my class:

```
def search(self, s):
    self.tableWidget.setCurrentItem(None)
    if not s:
        return
    matching_items = self.tableWidget.findItems(s, Qt.MatchContains)
    if matching_items:
        for item in matching_items:
            item.setSelected(True)
```

**My Question #1**
Now I'm confused where do the `s` parameter come from?

**My Question #2**
Also, how can I reuse this method so I can use this for multiple `QTableWidget`?

(I'm thinking about receiving the `QTableWidget` as an Argument but I can't proceed with that because I'm confused where do the `s` parameter come from)

**Edit:** I Changed the previous question, because I think It's not appropriate to ask it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *you* never call `self.search`; it's a bound method that will be called *for* you, with an appropriate argument, by the widget.

Comment: Ahh, I see ... One Question.
 If I change the `self.lineEdit_3.textChanged.connect(self.search)` to 
        `self.lineEdit_3.textChanged.connect(MyApp.search(self, s))`, 
 How can I access the value of parameter `s` argument if I wan't to pass it this way?

Comment: You can't pass it that way; `connect` expects something that can be called on a single argument: `self.search` is such a thing. `MyApp.search(self, s)` (assuming `s` were defined) is the *result* of the call.

Comment: You can, in some sense, think of `self.search` as the same as `lambda s: self.search(s)`.